# Software installation by group policy

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, group-policy, domain

I have a server with windows 2008 r2, it is connected N client. 
Clients use software that releases updates. 
Is there an application that I install on the server, which allows you to select the clients that once connected to the domain will update automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to Windows Updates, you can have them use either Automatic Updates straight from MS or setup WSUS on the server to centrally administer/approve client updates.  Or you can look into SCCM which could be used to also help administer 3rd party software as well.

If you are referring to 3rd party software that gets updated on the clients, then it's dependent on what 3rd party software it is and you'll have to work with that vendor or if it's in-house software you'll have to develop your own means of deploying updates.  Some can be packaged as .msi files using Software Installation via Group Policy, others can be done via a login script that checks for updates via various methods.  It really boils down to the application and how you can best administer it for your environment.

However, actual product recommendations themselves are Off-Topic here, so if you are asking for a specific software package to handle this for you or are wanting a "gimme the codez" then the question will most likely be closed.

Answer (score 2):

What TheCleaner said, but I'll add that it's often possible to deploy software updates through group policy or some other management software even if the vendor isn't super-forthcoming.  Many installers have [undocumented install switches](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php) because a lot of software uses the same install package software (you generally find these by trial and error, and you deploy this via group policy with a startup script).  Other installers sometimes unpack MSI files as a first step of the install, and you can "harvest" those for deployment.  Lastly, there are third party tools that repack installers as MSIs for group policy deployment.

(Yes, that's a lot of effort, but it's easier than clicking "next" on 5000 machines.)